# app crash. Templates

Tags: c++, list, templates

I tried to make my own version of the list container.I got the next problem doing this. My app compiled well, i placed implementation in header for template class, but when i attempt to run my app it crashes... i don't know what i've done wrong. Here's the code:

```
#ifndef _CH10EX8_
#define _CH10EX8_
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

template<typename T>
class List{
private:
    struct Item{
        Item* next;
        int index;
        T data;
};

    Item* head;

public:
    List();
    ~List();
    void addItem(const T&);
    void showList()const;
    T& getItem(int)const;
};


template<typename T>
List<T>::List()
{
  head = NULL;
};

template<typename T>
List<T>::~List()
{
  Item* current = head;
  Item* prev;
  while(current->next != NULL){
    prev = current;
    current = current->next;
    delete prev;
  }
  delete current;
  delete head;
}

template<typename T>
void List<T>::addItem(const T& val){
  static int index = 0;
  Item* toAdd = new Item;
  toAdd->data = val;
  toAdd->index = index;
  ++index;

  if(head == NULL){
    toAdd = head;
    head->next = NULL;
  }
  else{
    Item* current = head;
    while(current->next != NULL)
      current = current->next;

    current->next = toAdd;
    toAdd->next = NULL;
  }
}

template<typename T>
void List<T>::showList()const{
  Item* current = head;

  while(current->next != NULL)
    std::cout << "Data: " << current->data 
          << "At index: " << current->index << std::endl;
}
template<typename T>
T&  List<T>::getItem(int id)const{
  Item* current = head;
  if(current->index != id){
     while(current->next->index != id)
      {
    if(current->next == NULL){
      std::cout << "Item at index " << id << "not found\n";
      break;
    }
      }
    return current->data;
  }
  else
     return current->data;
}

#endif
```

that's for header. Here's my main:

```
    #include "ch10ex8.h"

int main(int argc,char** argv){

  List<double> m_list;

  for(double id = 0; id < 50.0; ++id)
    m_list.addItem(id);

  m_list.showList();

  std::cout << "Found item: " << m_list.getItem(20) << std::endl
        << "At index: " << 20 << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Now would be a good time to learn to use your debugger.

Comment: @AlanStokes and to tag questions properly. This has nothing to do with C at all.

Answer (score 1):

This piece of code is definitely buggy:

```
  if(head == NULL){
    toAdd = head;
    head->next = NULL;
  }
```

You can't do `head->next = NULL` if `head` is NULL.

Comment: yeah. I should've swapped them...That was the problem Access violation writing location 0x00000000. Cause of using NULL pointer. Thank you =)